# How to do a sql update statement with a join?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to do an update statement with the sum of another column from another table.  I want

```
customer_ar.current_bal to = sum(ar_transaction.current_balance)
```

As a test I ran this to make the customer_ar.current_bal=100 for 5 customers:

```
update customer_ar
set current_bal=100
where customer_id in (1502,1329,3096,1516,3605);
```

Next I ran this:

```
update customer_ar C
join ar_transaction T on T.customer_id=C.customer_id
set current_bal =
(select sum(current_balance)
from ar_transaction
where C.customer_id =T.customer_id)
where C.customer_id in (1502,1329,3096,1516,3605);
```

The result I got is that the balance for all of them became 213823.85.  The actual current balance should all be different for each customer, and between 50 and 100.

I can do a subquery and it'll work if I do it one at a time, but I'm trying to see if there's a way to have it do all of them at once.  Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please tag properly.  Which dbms????????  The syntax is different from one dbms to the other.

Comment: "SQL" is a standard for a query language. The standard does not contain any feature to "update with a join". So you **have** to tell us which DBMS product you are using. Postgres? Orace?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify.  We're using an old command line version at work.  Turns out it's sybase version 7.0.4.3345, so SQLanywhere version 7 if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql-server you can use this script.

```
update customer_ar 
set current_bal = 
    (select sum(current_balance)
        from ar_transaction T1
     where T1.customer_id =customer_ar.customer_id)
where customer_id in (1502,1329,3096,1516,3605);
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, this worked.  Looks like I didn't need the join the first place.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to group the rows in your sub-query to build the sum over the transactions per customer.

Maybe something like this (just to get the idea):

```
update customer_ar p
set current_bal = trans.sumBal
from customer_ar c
join (select customer_id, sum(current_bal) as sumBal from ar_transaction group by customer_id) trans on c.customer_id = trans.customer_id
where p.customer_id = trans.customer_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3dd88/14

**Update:**
Sorry for posting this invalid SQL. I've just fixed my example.

Comment: You assume OP is using SQL Server.  Never assume.

Comment: I did not assume anything. I personally never worked with "SQL Server".

Comment: Posting answer that does not work will only give you thumbs down.